# CloudComposer GKEStartPodOperator status is failed for long jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I have implemented an airflow DAG made up of the `GKEStartPodOperator` wrapper. This is the implementation of the operator :

```
pod1 = GKEStartPodOperator(
        task_id="pod-1",
        name="pod-1",
        project_id="Project1",
        location="Zone1",
        cluster_name="Cluster1",
        namespace="default",
        retries=2,
        image_pull_policy="Always",
        image="Image:v1")
```

The problem noticed is that when running longer-running jobs, the cloud composer takes the job as failed status first and only when on-job complete, changes it from failed to complete with the job run time. However, for a couple of jobs, the actual run time was not captured but the job did change from failed to complete.

I have tried the following but to no avail :

1. I have tried removing the retries as it might have affected the contact with the PID. However, that just resulted in the pod having to retry multiple times when the job status is detected to be failed.
2. I have tried running the pods in different clusters, setting them up to connect to clusters across the same or different VPN and namespaces to see if the behavior of the pods when spread across the clusters would be different.

I am curious if anyone has insights as to such a problem :

1. How is such a situation possible and what could have failed?
2. Is there any recommended changes to the POD operator definition that can help?
3. I have considered the `KubernetesPodOperator`, documentation found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html). However, there is a requirement to use the `GKEStartPodOperator`. However, if a solution does arise from using `KubernetesPodOperator` it can be considered.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Hi @kiranmathew no error message is returned. The logs show that jobs are running but stop running halfway. I have provided the `get_logs = True` but to no avail too.

Comment: Hi @Cosq, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.